# How can I create a new element/node and then add a new key and value to it?

Tags: java, xml

I have the following code:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
public class Xml2Json {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
    JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
    
    jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject("user").remove("age");
    
    jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").append("marks",23); }
}
```

it produces the output shown below:

```
{"users":{"report":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"marks":[23],"user":{"name":"test1"}}}
```

But I need to add a new element `newUser` to `users` and the marks should be inside the `newUser`, just like:

```
{"users":{"report":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"newUser":{"marks":{23}},"user":{"name":"test1"}}}
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your code use below mentioned code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

    String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
    JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);

    jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject("user").remove("age");

    Map<String, int[]> marks = new HashMap<>();
    marks.put("marks", new int[]{23});
    jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").put("newUser", marks);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
}
```

where line `jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").put("newUser", marks);` will add new `key(newUser)` with corresponding mapping marks as Map object.

**Without Map and HashMap:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

        String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);

        jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject("user").remove("age");

        JSONObject marksJSONObject = new JSONObject();
        marksJSONObject.put("marks",new int[]{23});
        jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").put("newUser", marksJSONObject);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"users":{"newUser":{"marks":[23]},"report":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"user":{"name":"test1"}}}
```

Comment: Map, HashMap cant be resolved to a type.. Could u pls help me to solve this?

Comment: What is the error that is throwing toward your side?

Comment: I have updated code to generate without Map and HashMap.

Answer (score -1):

```
    String xmlString = "<users><user name=test1 age=20></user><report sub=eng score=30></report></users>";
    JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xmlString);
    
    jsonObject.getJSONObject("users").getJSONObject("user").remove("age");

    JSONObject newUser = new JSONObject();
    
    newUser.put("marks", 32);

    jsonObject.put("newUser", newUser);
```

Comment: Compilation error and will generate unmatch JSON object.

Comment: Sorry, Which part of the code gets a compilation error?

Comment: missing of semi-colon.

Comment: And JSON generated will be `{"newUser":{"marks":32},"users":{"report":{"sub":"eng","score":30},"user":{"name":"test1"}}}
` which is not simillar